# Were Jews ever subjected to any oppression or targeting in the region of Egypt?

Tags: egypt, jews

[According to](https://www.timesofisrael.com/liveblog_entry/in-meeting-with-blinken-sissi-claims-jews-were-never-persecuted-in-egypt/) Egyptian President Abdel-Fattah el-Sissi ([alternative link](https://www.document.no/2023/10/15/sissi-joder-var-aldri-forfulgt-i-egypt/)):

> I am an Egyptian person who grew up next to Jews in Egypt. They have never been subjected to any form of oppression or targeting and it has never happened in our region that Jews were targeted

Is this true?

Comment: The URL is broken, but that's such laughable propaganda...  Not totally clear what he means by "in our region" though. FWTW quote seems to be from something like https://www.timesofisrael.com/?post_type=liveblog_entry&p=3124277#:~:text=%E2%80%9CYou%20said%20that%20you%20are,region%20that%20Jews%20were%20targeted.%E2%80%9D or any other source quoting that recent meeting with Blinken.

Comment: "Why, where I grew up we weren't none of us any racist at all, all this talk of racism is just nonsense." -- every single racist grandma who insists she isn't.

Comment: The quote implies relatively recent times, specifically the modern country of Egypt. However, the title count imply the region itself, including antiquity, which would be a *much* broader subject.

Comment: Is your claim that the whole Mozes story, and the biblical story exodus didn't happen?

Answer (score 19):

Well, Sisi was born in 1954. So let's say he missed the stuff from before then, although, [for the record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Jews_in_Egypt#After_the_foundation_of_Israel_in_1948):

> After the foundation of Israel in 1948, and the subsequent 1948 Arab–Israeli War, in which Egypt participated, difficulties multiplied for Egyptian Jews, who then numbered 75,000. That year, bombings of Jewish areas killed 70 Jews and wounded nearly 200, while riots claimed many more lives. [...] Amidst the violence, many Egyptian Jews emigrated abroad. By 1950, nearly 40% of Egypt's Jewish population had emigrated.

or when he was still a baby:

> In the immediate aftermath of trilateral invasion on 23 November 1956 by Britain, France, and Israel (known as the Suez Crisis), a proclamation was issued stating that 'all Jews are Zionists and enemies of the state',[citation needed] and it promised that they would be soon expelled. Some 25,000 Jews, almost half of the Jewish community left for Israel, Europe, the United States, and South America, after being forced to sign declarations that they were leaving "voluntarily" and to agree with the confiscation of their assets. Some 1,000 more Jews were imprisoned. Similar measures were enacted against British and French nationals in retaliation for the invasion.
>
> UN High Commissioner for Refugees Auguste Lindt stated in his Report to the UNREF Executive Committee's Fourth Session (Geneva 29 January to 4 February 1957) "Another emergency problem is now arising: that of refugees from Egypt. [...]

But when he was a teenager:

> After the Six-Day War in 1967, more confiscations took place. Rami Mangoubi, who lived in Cairo at the time, said that nearly all Egyptian Jewish men between the ages of 17 and 60 were either thrown out of the country immediately, or taken to the detention centers of Abou Za'abal and Tura, where they were incarcerated and tortured for more than three years. The eventual result was the almost-complete disappearance of the 3,000-year-old Jewish community in Egypt; the vast majority of Jews left the country. [...]

As for nowadays:

> As of December 2022, there are only 3 Egyptian Jews living in Egypt [...]

I just used Wikipedia as source here, because these facts are not exactly controversial in the West, I think. The quote tagged as "citation needed" can indeed be found in many books, on a quick search. I have no idea what--state controlled--Egyptian history manuals say; presumably the state line that Jews all left "voluntarily".

Comment: FWTW, during the brief "Arab Spring" in Egypt, there was one presidential adviser who tried to break with the official line, and even called for reparations to be paid to Jews who were expelled. But he was quickly sacked. https://www.thecairoreview.com/tahrir-forum/new-spotlight-on-egyptian-jews/

Comment: "a proclamation was issued" — by whom?  Anyone can proclaim anything.

Comment: @gerrit: the other answer says "by the Minister of Religious Affairs".

Comment: @gerrit on the 20th a law was passed canceling the citizenship of Jews.  Then on the 23th Sheikh El Bakouri ordered Muslims to withdraw all contact with Jews because the government would be expelling them.  (*Regional Development for Regional Peace*, 1957).

Answer (score 13):

According to the [Jewish Virtual Library](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jews-of-egypt), there were 75,000 Jews in Egypt in 1948, in 2020 there remains less than 100. They explain why

> Between June and November 1948, bombs set off in the Jewish Quarter of
> Cairo killed more than 70 Jews and wounded nearly 200. **In 1956, the
> Egyptian government used the Sinai Campaign as a pretext for expelling
> almost 25,000 Egyptian Jews and confiscating their property.**
> Approximately 1,000 more Jews were sent to prisons and detention
> camps.
>
> On November 23, 1956, a proclamation signed by the Minister of
> Religious Affairs, and read aloud in mosques throughout Egypt,
> declared that “**all Jews are Zionists and enemies of the state,” and
> promised that they would be soon expelled. Thousands of Jews were
> ordered to leave the country.** They were allowed to take only one
> suitcase and a small sum of cash and forced to sign declarations
> “donating” their property to the Egyptian government.
>
> Foreign
> observers reported that members of Jewish families were taken hostage,
> apparently to insure that those forced to leave did not speak out
> against the Egyptian government.

See also "Only 100 Jews remain in Egypt out of a population that topped 80,000 in 1948" (from [here](https://www.worldjewishcongress.org/en/about/communities/EG)).